# Run / Build Apk is not updated with the latest changes

Tags: android, vue.js, cordova

I have a problem in my **vuejs + cordova project**, when there is an edit file for example (login.vue) the changes only appear when running the 'npm run serve' command but when running the command 'cordova run browser / android' the login.vue file is not updated. I've tried clear cache 'npm clear cache' and 'cordova clean / cordova prepare' the results are still the same.

Command Before run/build cordova :

- npm run serve
- npm run build
- cd cordova_app
- cordova run/build android or browser

Answer (score 0):

it is because the latest changes you made to files need to be brought to the platform folder `(E.g. $projectroot/platform/android/www)`.

For this you have two options:

- you can edit the file here directly
  `$projectroot/platform/$platform_name/www`, but as a result, if you delete the platform, then that change will get lost.
- Or you can make also make the changes in `$projectroot/www/` but you will need to run few commands: `cordova platform remove android` and `cordova platform add android` if it is for Android. Please note that this will also overwrite any special configuration you have made in your IDE (xCode for iOS or Android Studio for Android) because it regenerates from your code, a new workspace for your app to be compiled, including your latest code, all in the platform folder.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Bastien, thanks for your response. I have tried both options but it still doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Have you tried to delete package.json and package lock?